# I’m trying to get the object key “brand” and its value into a new array but I’m having trouble

Tags: javascript

```js
const object = [{
  color: "red",
  brand: "honda",
  speed: "159hp"
}, {
  color: "blue",
  brand: "BMW",
  speed: "435hp"
}]
const result = object.map(carBrand => {
  carBrand.filter(carBrand.indexOf(1))
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Each `carBrand` is an object, which doesn't have `filter` or `indexOf` properties. Also you don't show _any_ array for which `indexOf(1)` would be anything other than `-1`. I'd strongly recommend a structured tutorial, your approach so far makes no sense.

Comment: State clearly what do You want to achieve? Do you want console to print `['honda' , 'BMW']` ? Or is it something else You need

Comment: Do you want `['brand', 'Honda']` or `[{ brand: 'Honda' }]`?

Comment: How would I I get both results @Andy

Comment: @ryanyeaman I've added a couple of examples of both outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Based off your last comment it depends what you want your output to be.

Here we're adding new objects to an array:

```js
const arr=[{color:"red",brand:"honda",speed:"159hp"},{color:"blue",brand:"BMW",speed:"435hp"}];

const result = arr.map(obj => {
  return { brand: obj.brand };
});

console.log(result);
```

Here we're adding new arrays to the array:

```js
const arr=[{color:"red",brand:"honda",speed:"159hp"},{color:"blue",brand:"BMW",speed:"435hp"}];

const result = arr.map(obj => {
  return [ 'brand', obj.brand ];
});

console.log(result);
```